# Assimp not properly loading indices

Tags: parsing, directx, indices, 3ds, assimp

I'm trying to load simple 3d model cube.3ds, but next error occurs: when I read indices to my vector, vector contains: [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]. It's not properly. I found almost the same topic: [Assimp and D3D model loading: Mesh not being displayed in D3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820973/assimp-and-d3d-model-loading-mesh-not-being-displayed-in-d3d), but I don't found the answer. Can anyone describe in detail properly algorithm for loading indices from meshes. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a example pulled from the assimp sample code on accessing the mesh indices.

```
for (; n < nd->mNumMeshes; ++n) 
{
    const struct aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[nd->mMeshes[n]];

    apply_material(sc->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex]);

    if(mesh->mNormals == NULL) {
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    } else {
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    }

    for (t = 0; t < mesh->mNumFaces; ++t) {
        const struct aiFace* face = &mesh->mFaces[t];
        GLenum face_mode;

        switch(face->mNumIndices) {
            case 1: face_mode = GL_POINTS; break;
            case 2: face_mode = GL_LINES; break;
            case 3: face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES; break;
            default: face_mode = GL_POLYGON; break;
        }

        glBegin(face_mode);

        for(i = 0; i < face->mNumIndices; i++) {
            int index = face->mIndices[i];
            if(mesh->mColors[0] != NULL)
                glColor4fv((GLfloat*)&mesh->mColors[0][index]);
            if(mesh->mNormals != NULL) 
                glNormal3fv(&mesh->mNormals[index].x);
            glVertex3fv(&mesh->mVertices[index].x);
        }

        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. But my mistake was in other place. When I read scene via assimp, I'v just passed only aiProcess_Triangulate flags, but for properly loading indices also need to pass aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices.